# Running gradle application by IntellIj

Tags: java, spring, intellij-idea, jhipster

When I run application (jHipster) by command linie (gradlew) everything is working but when I try run application with IntellIJ (by button) 
[image]

I have a error:

```
2017-07-24 21:43:13.313 DEBUG 4312 --- [  restartedMain] c.e.c.E.p.t.d.S.preferredDivisions       : Close successful.
2017-07-24 21:43:13.493 ERROR 4312 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.d.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter   : 

***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Parameter 1 of constructor in com.patres.timetable.service.DivisionService required a bean of type 'com.patres.timetable.service.mapper.DivisionMapper' that could not be found.


Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'com.patres.timetable.service.mapper.DivisionMapper' in your configuration.


Process finished with exit code 0
```

All my classes were generated by jHipster. For example DivisionMapper looks like this:

```
@Mapper(componentModel = "spring", uses = {UserMapper.class, TeacherMapper.class, SubjectMapper.class, })
public interface DivisionMapper extends EntityMapper <DivisionDTO, Division> {

    @Mapping(target = "timetables", ignore = true)
    @Mapping(target = "divisionPlaces", ignore = true)
    @Mapping(target = "divisionTeachers", ignore = true)
    @Mapping(target = "divisionSubjects", ignore = true)
    @Mapping(target = "divisionLessons", ignore = true)
    @Mapping(target = "divisionPeriods", ignore = true)
    @Mapping(target = "divisionProperties", ignore = true)
    @Mapping(target = "preferredPlaces", ignore = true)
    Division toEntity(DivisionDTO divisionDTO); 
    default Division fromId(Long id) {
        if (id == null) {
            return null;
        }
        Division division = new Division();
        division.setId(id);
        return division;
    }
}
```

Can someone explain this to me? For this same error I can't run unit test in IDE

Step by step to reproduce issue:

1) Generate jhipster application:

```
{
  "generator-jhipster": {
    "promptValues": {
      "packageName": "com.patres.timetable",
      "nativeLanguage": "en"
    },
    "jhipsterVersion": "4.6.2",
    "baseName": "Test",
    "packageName": "com.patres.timetable",
    "packageFolder": "com/patres/timetable",
    "serverPort": "8080",
    "authenticationType": "jwt",
    "hibernateCache": "ehcache",
    "clusteredHttpSession": false,
    "websocket": false,
    "databaseType": "sql",
    "devDatabaseType": "postgresql",
    "prodDatabaseType": "postgresql",
    "searchEngine": "elasticsearch",
    "messageBroker": false,
    "serviceDiscoveryType": "eureka",
    "buildTool": "gradle",
    "enableSocialSignIn": false,
    "jwtSecretKey": "18817051906d7b75a7c8c96ac82de44228e55742",
    "clientFramework": "angularX",
    "useSass": true,
    "clientPackageManager": "yarn",
    "applicationType": "monolith",
    "testFrameworks": [],
    "jhiPrefix": "jhi",
    "enableTranslation": true,
    "nativeLanguage": "en",
    "languages": [
      "en",
      "pl"
    ]
  }
}
```

2) Generate simply entity

```
entity Division {
    name String required,
    shortName String,
    numberOfPeople Long,
    colorBackground String,
    colorText String
}

paginate all with pagination
service all with serviceClass

dto * with mapstruct
```

3) Configure database in application-dev.yml

4) Run in IntellIJ with error (but with command line gradlew everything is OK)

5) Link to github with this example https://github.com/Patresss/jHipster

Comment: Can you open the run configurations and take a screenshot of however that is configured?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just a little update:

```
plugins {
    id 'net.ltgt.apt-idea' version '0.13'
}

apply plugin: 'idea'
apply plugin: "net.ltgt.apt"

dependencies {
    apt "org.mapstruct:mapstruct-processor:${mapstruct_version}"
    apt "org.hibernate:hibernate-jpamodelgen:${hibernate_version}"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I found a solution! I just add this in my build.gradle:

```
plugins {
    id 'net.ltgt.apt' version '0.9'
}

apply plugin: 'idea'
apply plugin: "net.ltgt.apt"
```

The problem was with annotation processors (from mapstruct)